# jQuery UI Accordion CSS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am planning to use the jQuery UI Accordion and also the default theme provided

I see that the jQuery UI Accordion uses the following classes from this url [link text](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css)

```
<div class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset">
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"/>
    <a href="#">Section 1</a>
  </h3>
  <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active">
    Section 1 content
  </div>
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>
    <a href="#">Section 2</a>
  </h3>
  <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    Section 2 content
  </div>
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>
    <a href="#">Section 3</a>
  </h3>
  <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    Section 3 content
  </div>
</div>
```

I do not want to use the entire CSS from the theme file, just the ones required for the UI Accordion. However I am not able to create the same effect. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-ui-accordion-css/

> updated to latest jQuery version 10

you don't need to have all that code! you have copied the jquery example that explane how jquery create the full accordion widget!

you just need to have like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">  
  <h3><a href="#">caption 1</a></h3>  
  <div>some text here    
  </div><h3><a href="#">caption 2</a></h3>  
  <div>some text here    
  </div><h3><a href="#">caption 3</a></h3>  
  <div>some text here    
  </div><h3><a href="#">caption 4</a></h3>  
  <div>some text here    
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery / JS**

```
$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1px;
  zoom: 1;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-li-fix {
  display: inline;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header-active {
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
}
/* IE7-/Win - Fix extra vertical space in lists */
.ui-accordion a {
  zoom: 1;
}
.ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-header a {
  padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: .5em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
  padding: 1em 2.2em;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: -2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
  zoom: 1;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active {
  display: block;
}
```

> **NOTE:** this minimum css require also the .ui-widget CSS see the demo!

Comment: yes but you do not get that effect - like th headers are not highlighted and so on

Comment: hi, i have implement like this, but this is one is missing the arrow icon.How can i add that icone?

Comment: @Hsakarp hi look at the demo, i have updated it... just look at the souce code. hope it help.

Answer (score 6):

In the [jQuery UI Download page](http://jqueryui.com/download) you can select the parts of the javascript and css you need. If you deselect all and then select the Accordion widget you will get only the JavaScript and CSS for the accordion in your download.

Answer (score 1):

For the highlighting effect and everything use this css

```
.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
border: 1px solid #999999/*{borderColorHover}*/;
background: #dadada/*{bgColorHover}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png)/*{bgImgUrlHover}*/ 50%/*{bgHoverXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgHoverYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgHoverRepeat}*/;
font-weight: normal/*{fwDefault}*/;
color: #212121/*{fcHover}*/;
}
.ui-state-hover a,
.ui-state-hover a:hover,
.ui-state-hover a:link,
.ui-state-hover a:visited {
color: #212121/*{fcHover}*/;
text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorActive}*/;
background: #ffffff/*{bgColorActive}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png)/*{bgImgUrlActive}*/ 50%/*{bgActiveXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgActiveYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgActiveRepeat}*/;
font-weight: normal/*{fwDefault}*/;
color: #212121/*{fcActive}*/;
}
.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
color: #212121/*{fcActive}*/;
text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
margin-top: 2px;
padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
min-height: 0; /* support: IE7 */
border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}


.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header :hover{background-color:#f7f7f7;}


.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons {
padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-noicons {
padding-left: .7em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-icons {
padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {
position: absolute;
left: .5em;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -8px;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
padding: 2em 1.2em;
border-top: 0;
overflow: auto;
}
```